# Disable Fancy Box Close Function on Cross Icon and on HTML Body Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fancybox-2

I want to Disable Fancy Box **Close Function** when user clicks on **Cross Icon** or he clicks on **HTML Body anywhere**. The Popup Should be closed only when user clicks on "Close Fancy Box" button placed in the popup.

```
$(".fancybox-effects-b").fancybox({
    openEffect: 'none',
    closeEffect: 'none',
    helpers: {
        title: {
            type: 'over'
        }
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/PFVxK/1364/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the docs you can use these options:

```
helpers : {overlay:{ closeClick: false } }
closeBtn: false
closeClick: false
```

For close the box programmatically: `$.fancybox.close();`

Ref: http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/mdfQ4/

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".fancybox-effects-b").fancybox({
     openEffect  : 'none',
     closeEffect : 'none',
     tpl:{
        closeBtn : '<a id="close" class="fancybox-close" href="javascript"> Close Fancy box</a>',
     },
     helpers : {
     overlay : {
    closeClick : false,  // if true, fancyBox will be closed when user clicks on the overlay
    },
     title : {
        type : 'over'
     }
   }
  });
 })
```

and also see this jsfiddle i updated html and css

http://jsfiddle.net/PFVxK/1367/

updated as you want.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest : add `modal: true` to your API options

```
$(".fancybox-effects-b").fancybox({
    openEffect: 'none',
    closeEffect: 'none',
    helpers: {
        title: {
            type: 'over'
        }
    },
    modal: true // prevents closing fancybox and disable close button (unless using $.fancybox.close() method) 
});
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/r5qjt/)**